# Why is this request returning random noise?

Tags: python, terminal, python-requests

I'm new to coding. I tried to run a script in VS code and kept getting this weird "gibberish" in my terminal. What could be wrong with it? Is it something to do with encoding perhaps?

[image: this is how it looks]

This is the whole script, it is written in Python

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/sport/football/events/live"

payload = ""
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Referer": "https://www.sofascore.com/",
    "Origin": "https://www.sofascore.com",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
    "If-None-Match": "W/c1f9e171df",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "TE": "trailers"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I got this script from Youtube, the guy who posted this exact same script got normal readable data.

Comment: What's the script? We need to see a [mre]. That output looks like just random noise, and in fact if I do `head -c1000 /dev/random | sed 's/\s\|\e//g'` (a chunk of random noise without whitespace or escape characters), I can get pretty similar output. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips. You can [edit].

Comment: added the script, don't know if thats any help

Comment: What language is that, Python?

Comment: yes thats python

Comment: Well, the script doesn't seem to be handling random noise, but I don't know what exactly it is doing; I'm out of my depth. Did you confirm the issue is VSCode-specific? I mean if you run the code in another terminal, does it work as expected? If it also doesn't work there, you should update the question, like "Why is this request returning random noise?" and add the Python tag and remove the VSCode one.

Comment: Well, I tried to run the script in cmd through notepad++ and still got the "gibberish" answer. I will edit the post

Comment: "Random noise" is what ideally compressed data looks like. If you can't handle compressed content, why are you sending headers that say you can? `"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"` _explicitly_ promises to handle data compressed in any one of three different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the `response.headers` you'll notice `Content-Encoding: br`. The data you see is compressed with the Brotli compression algorithm; you'll need to uncompress it. Or, don't claim that you support `br` in `Accept-Encoding:`

According to https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4525, `requests` will transparently decode the data if you have either the `brotli` or `brotlicffi` package installed via `pip`, so that's probably how the Youtuber solved it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this fixed it. I also found that if "br" is replaced by "utf-8" then it also fixes the problem

Comment: `utf-8` is not a valid content encoding but if you replaced `br` with `utf-8` in the `Accept-Encoding:` header, the remote sever will simply have ignored it. See also e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-content-encoding/